# Having trouble understanding what caused this segmentation fault (C-style strings in C++)

Tags: c++, string, pointers

This problem comes from a textbook: Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition) By Bjarne Stroustrup.

Note: I have solved the problem, the question comes from my lack of understanding as to how my earlier attempts at a solution failed. I know it is a long question but I feel that it is important to understand this concept.

Here is the problem:

> Write a function, char* findx(const char* s, const char* x), that finds the first occurrence of a C-style string x in s.

I could easily have looked up the solution (or alter the way the function is declared) but if I feel like this issue is the whole point of the exercise, so I held off on that. Feel free to correct any wrong statements I make in this question. Also, forgive me if this is an over complication but I really don't understand this.

For starters, here is my function written in a way that compiles, but causes a segfault at runtime:

```
char* findx(const char* s, const char* x) {

  if (s==nullptr || x == nullptr) return nullptr;   //if no string, return nullptr
  int s_size = strlen(s);            
  int x_size = strlen(x);
  char* ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;                 //initialize pointer to 1st occ

  for (int i = 0; i < (s_size-x_size); ++i) {       //end with the last char that 
                                                    //can hold string x to the end
    for (int j = i; j < x_size; ++j) {              //check if the first char match
        if (s[j] != x[j]) ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr; //if it doesn't, set to 0
                                                     //and move on
        else ptr_to_first_occ = (char*)(s) + i;      //set equal to first occ if ==
    }
  }
  if (ptr_to_first_occ) return ptr_to_first_occ;
  else return nullptr;
}
```

Here is main:

```
const char* y = "Hey how are you?";
const char* t = "you";
char* p = nullptr;
p = findx(y, t);
cout << *p << endl;
```

The only reason this compiles is due to the fact that I cast the const char s to char*, which is not the right way to do things, but I am pretty sure the segfault is not caused by this as my solution includes the cast.

My goal here is to return a pointer to the memory location that holds the first character of string x in string s. The problem is that the first character itself is contained within a string that is passed as const in the first place, so the pointer to it is of type const char *, not char* as is the pointer that I declare. If I want to declare ptr_to_first_occ as a const char*, I can no longer assign the proper location to it since it is not writeable. This leaves me to either completely change the function (I am expected to return a char*, I could probably do it another way rather quickly) or to use a cast. Or I can change that part as such:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (s_size-x_size); ++i) {
       for (int j = i; j < x_size; ++j) {
           if (s[j] != x[j]) ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;
           else {
               const char* ptr_to_first_occ = &s[i];
           }   
       }
    }
```

Problem is that the declaration makes it so that this variable only exists within the scope of that else, and I can't use a dummy variable to store that const char* before the the pointer goes out of scope, because I can't assign to const variables that were declared before.

At this point I realize that this:

```
for (int j = i; j < x_size; ++j) {...}
```

makes no sense, and should actually be:

```
for (int j = i; j < i + x_size; ++j) {...}
```

Alright, fair enough. My function is now this:

```
    char* findx(const char* s, const char* x) {
        if (s==nullptr || x == nullptr) return nullptr;
        int s_size = strlen(s);
        int x_size = strlen(x);
        char* ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;

        for (int i = 0; i < (s_size-x_size); ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j < i+x_size; ++j) {
                if (s[j] != x[j]) ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;
                else {
                    ptr_to_first_occ = (char*)&s[i];
                }
            }
        }
        if (ptr_to_first_occ) return ptr_to_first_occ;
        else return nullptr;
    }
```

Compiles, and logically seems to work, but I still get a segfault due to the same reason I suspect (Segmentation fault: 11). I now change main to this:

```
const char* y = "Hey how are you?";
const char* t = "you";
char* p = nullptr;
p = findx(y, t);
if (p) cout << *p << endl;
```

Turns out that this prints nothing, so p must have remained a nullptr. Anyway, after many debugging flags, and a bunch of trial and error (read: rewriting the function in a way that made it look like a dumpster) I cleaned up the whole thing, and managed to solve the problem:

```
    char* findx(const char* s, const char* x) {
        if (s==nullptr || x == nullptr) return nullptr;
        int s_size = strlen(s);
        int x_size = strlen(x);
        char* ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;

        for (int i = 0; i < (s_size-x_size); ++i) {
            if (s[i] != x[0]) ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;
            else {
                for (int k = 0; k < x_size; ++k) {
                    if (s[i+k] == x[k]) ptr_to_first_occ = (char*)&s[i];
                    else {
                        ptr_to_first_occ = nullptr;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (ptr_to_first_occ) return ptr_to_first_occ;
        else {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
```

Which means that the cast had nothing to do with the segmentation fault, and this is essentially where my question comes from. I simply could not track down the reason for the fault in my earlier code. I would like some input as to how to understand the cause of a segmentation fault as it relates to memory locations, since my understanding of how the read only memory locations work was wrong. What was I trying to do that caused my error?

Comment: C++ and C are two separate languages.  Please pick one.

Comment: You are learning - so the next thing is to learn is the debugger.  This example is perfect for stepping through and seeing how the variables change.

Comment: Instead of guessing what happens, use the debugger that comes with your compiler.  Second, I don't recommend rewriting code and not know what you're doing to fix the problem.  That is just throwing stuff on the wall and hoping something sticks.  Figure out why your original program failed, and then given that information, rewrite the code that fixes the errors you discovered.  Also, there is such a thing as undefined behavior in C++ -- just because your code "works" now doesn't mean it actually works.  That goes back to figuring out why your original program failed..

Comment: Would be desired to add check of sizes of both strings. Think what would happen when "s" is shorter than "x" (hint: `i < (s_size-x_size)`).

Comment: Paul - I agree, I did say that I solved the problem, not thoroughly tested it! I must say that I was not doing random things to see what works, I just omitted a large part of how I got the solution (mainly because I happened to be really focused as I started getting closer to the solution).

Comment: Rich - I will take your word for that one. I have been meaning to start learning how to use gdm after all...                                                                       Anty - Yeah, that would be wise.

Comment: @gasoline Well, if you take a birds-eye view of your first attempt, that loop cannot work correctly.  You have two different strings, and the indices you will be comparing characters must be different, not the same.  Thus comparing `s[ j ]` to `x[ j ]` will not work correctly for the data you passed in, since `j` is not going to be right for both strings at the same time.

Comment: Paul - For sure. That was the error that led me to restructuring the solution.

Comment: 1) As this is clearly C++, why don't you use the string type? Writing C-style code is bad practice if your language provides easier ways. 2) Read the documentation of the functions you use. E.g. `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not `int`. 3) Never ever use casts if you don't understand all implications. Casting away `const` is almost always an indicator of other problems in the code, and it is in your code.

Comment: Olaf - this is a textbook problem that is why I am doing it with c strings. Otherwise I agree with you.